# Eloquent relation Works fine in Development Environment but in production server shows Error: trying to get property from non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am not much experienced in Laravel and facing some strange issues.
I have been working on a simple project. In my local development environment where I use xampp on windows, the website works perfectly well but after uploading the project to the live server some of the relations do not work properly or I should say they behave in a very strange way.

The below block of code returns error: 'trying to get property from non object' in my case.

```
@foreach($transactions as $transaction)
  <td>{{$transaction->Methodtype->name}}</td>
  <td>{{$transaction->Gateway->name}}</td>
@endforeach
```

My controller file includes the below

```
public function transactions() {
    $transactions = Transaction::where(['trxndeleted' => '0'])->get();
    return view('layouts.pages.transactions', compact('transactions'));
}
```

However when I return results directly to check then I get required data. Please see below.

```
public function transactions() {
    $transactions = Transaction::where(['trxndeleted' => '0'])->get();
    return $transactions[0]->Methodtype;
}
```

My Transaction and Methodtype models look like below

Transaction Model:

```
public function Methodtype() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\methodtype', 'methodtype_id');
}
```

Methodtype Model:

```
public function Transaction() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction', 'methodtype_id');
}
```

Comment: 1. Are the environments identical (phpversion, activated plugins, etc...)? 2. Have you checked your `.env` file? Maybe you still run some development configs. 3. Why not `$this->belongsTo(Methodtype::class, 'methodtype_id');` 4. Is you Methodtypeclass really named `methodtype`? If not it won't be recognizes.

Comment: Are you sure that Methodtype and Gateway are never null? If they are null for even only 1 transaction, you will get that error

Comment: Hi @Soundz, I have checked but found nothing wrong with the .env file.  The same script works perfectly in my laptop's development environment.  This started after I uploaded my project to a shared hosting environment.

Comment: @gbalduzzi, Thanks man, You are right. I found unfortunately one record had null value.

Comment: Happy to help :)